# Deque random acces O(n) in python while O(1) in C++, why?

Tags: python, deque

C++ [deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque):

> Random access - constant O(1)

Python [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle.

If I'm not missing anything, everything else is equally fast for deques in python and in C++, at least complexity-wise. Is there anything that makes python's deque better for some cases? If not, why don't they just switch to what C++ has?

Comment: Implementation details. In both cases.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Isn't that a tautology?

Comment: @Sneftel What do you mean exactly by "tautology"? That everything is an inmplementation detail?

Comment: @Sneftel: No, because both of OP's sources are specifications, not implementations. And it is entirely possible that further specifications make it impossible to formulate an improved implementation.

Comment: Random access isn't the central concern of deques. Rather it's a side-effect of the method chosen to get fast push/pop on both ends. Python uses a linked list and C++ STLs tend to use a vector-of-chunks. Consequently, Python inserts are very nearly guaranteed constant time: memory allocation for a new list node plus value initialization. Unfortunately access to arbitrary elements of a linked list is O(n). The vector-of-chunks allows quick random access, but can require O(n) time to reorganize the map vector for any given insert (though n inserts require O(n) time).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't understand why this matters, my question is about the specifications, not any specific implementations.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134139/why-is-deque-implemented-as-a-linked-list-instead-of-a-circular-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: this answer is largely inspired from Jeff's comment and the answer already posted at [Why is a deque implemented as a linked list instead of a circular array ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134139/why-is-deque-implemented-as-a-linked-list-instead-of-a-circular-array)

Your question is different in nature but the title above is an answer in itself: in Python, the module collections.deque has a linear time complexity when accessing items in the middle because it is implemented using a linked list.

From the pydoc:

> A list-like sequence optimized for data accesses near its endpoints.

Now if you're wondering **why** this implementation was chosen, the answer is already available in the post pointed out by Jeff.

Answer (score -1):

Because Deque is a data structed supposed to be used in a specific way, being accessed by the first or last element, 
But python sometimes do weird things with its data structures and add more functions to them, or use composed data structures

In this case python has the function

```
remove(value)
#Remove the first occurrence of value. If not found, raises a ValueError.
```

this allow you to access the data structure elements on the middle of the deque it isn't a "core" operation of this data structure,

causing the  "but slows to O(n) in the middle. "

Because in this case it behaves like an array (checking values one by one)