# Do C++ Standard Library types implement exception-safe copy-assignment?

Tags: c++, exception, stl

I've recently come to appreciate the copy-and-swap idiom, and have been using it to implement copy-assignment for any class which manages a resource.  So it got me thinking about Standard Library types: does the standard guarantee exception-safe behavior?

For example, consider a class that contains one `std::string` data member.  Ordinarily, I wouldn't have implemented my own copy-assignement, etc., but is this safe?  Does the standard guarantee that the `std::string` data member is left unchanged if the copy-assignment fails?  Would it be beneficial to implement copy-and-swap in this case -- or is that just going too far?

Comment: Given that for all relevant compilers, these are used by thousands of important programs, it would be really embarrassing and critical if these implementations contained such well-known and avoidable flaws... so I'd just assume the stdlib works.

Comment: @delnan: I'd have thought that too, and then I learned how absolutely wretched the Microsoft/Dinkumware implementation of `std::deque` is...

Comment: @DeadMG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088999/what-the-heque-is-going-on-with-the-memory-overhead-of-stddeque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard specifies explicitely in 'verse' 21.4.1.2. that any other exceptions other than `std::bad_length` "shall have no effect".

Comment: Are you referring to the C++03 standard?  Can you provide the whole clause for some context?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that copy assignment for std::string would throw is if dynamic allocation failed, in which case you (arguably) are totally screwed anyway. The Standard library is *the* example of C++ design, and I don't think that they would have overlooked such a thing. I wouldn't go to the trouble of checking Standard types.

Comment: Arguably indeed. Maybe I'm managing overall heap usage, and I can recover from `std::bad_alloc`. I would want to know if my `std::string` object is in a valid state (e.g., it won't blow up when it goes out of scope).  I'm asking if the standard requires it -- you didn't answer my question.

Comment: @Tabber33: Even in a managed heap, recovering from bad_alloc is a decidedly non-trivial operation. I answered the question - it is going too far.

Comment: I realize the question is pedantic -- so I'll wait for an answer from someone who can appreciate why it's being asked.  I'm not debating the merit of handling `bad_alloc` -- it's incidental to the question.

Comment: @Tabber33: I seriously don't get it. You asked if it was going to far, and I've answered that it is.

Comment: No, you seriously don't get it.  I'm asking what the standard says on the matter.  Your opinion that it's going too far is duly noted.  I like to pretent that there is mission-critical code out there where this would actually need to be considered.  It's a valid question.