# C++ STL queue memory usage compared to vector?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, queue

I was wondering just exactly how much more memory the queue uses in comparison to the vector. I was having an issue the other day where I had an array of int queues that used around 60MB and when the same data was put in a vector of vectors it used around 4MB. Is this an error on my part in coding the program or do stl queues generally use more memory than vectors?

Comment: An `std::queue` is just a container adapter that wraps functional exposure to an underlying sequence class, including sequences such as `std::list`, `std::vector`, and `std::deque`, the latter being the default. Without knowing which underlying container you were using, it is hard to say. Using `std::list` would add significant per-element overhead, since each element would be given two additional member data (fore and aft pointers). Ultimately, though, it is implementation-depndent. Now, an *order of magnitude* different in your case, thats a little suspect.

Comment: I had `queue<int> stuff[100000]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `std::queue` is a container adaptor, not a container itself.  So let's compare the overhead of some actual containers:

- `std::vector` is very memory-efficient, it uses almost zero overhead.  A `std::vector<int>` uses about 4 bytes per item, on most platforms.
- `std::list` is very inefficient with memory, it will likely use two pointers of overhead per item.  A `std::list<int>` uses about 24 bytes per item, on 64-bit platforms, and 12 bytes on 32-bit platforms.
- `std::deque` is between the two, and it is the default container for `std::queue`.  According to ["what the heck is going on with the memory overhead of `std::deque`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088999/what-the-heque-is-going-on-with-the-memory-overhead-of-stddeque), the MSVC deque is a list of blocks each containing around 16 bytes, which is quite a bit of overhead if your queues contain one or two `int` each and you have a lot of queues.

Another factor that affects overhead is the efficiency of the allocator on your platform, which will color your results unless you can account for it.  A 15x difference between two implementations is so large it's downright suspicious — it makes me wonder how you got those numbers.

*In general,* if your queues are very short, there is a lot of room for improvement over the other implementations.  If you're okay with writing your own container, you could write a circular buffer container or use [Boost's `circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html).  A circular buffer combines the memory efficiency of `std::vector` with the CPU efficiency of `std::deque` for deque type operations.  Kind of makes me wish it were in the STL to begin with.  Oh well.

#### Footnote

The actual amounts of overhead will vary with the implementation.